# DTSwiss rear wheel hub part name

Tags: rear-wheel, wheels

I want to buy a used bike (Specialized Tarmac) with good price
But rear wheel hub is broken as in photo
[image]
What is a part name I have to buy and change, or it must be completely changed
PS: I don't know exact model name, but on it Ultegra 67xx 11 chains

UPDATE:
The wheelset model DT Swiss Axis 3.0

Comment: *Ultegra 67xx 11 chains*? What do you mean by that? Ultegra 6700 series is 10-speed. About the bike?  It needs a new rear wheel - it's almost certainly cheaper to buy a new rear wheel than it would be to get a replacement hub, new spokes, and rebuild the wheel.  I'd also check the front wheel closely, too.  A cracked hub like that can be caused by overtensioning the spokes while trying to true the wheel, and if that happened to the rear wheel it may have happened to the front.

Comment: I found wheel model. It is : DT Swiss Axis 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part which is broken is called the flange of the hub, however these aren't replaceable. You'd need a whole new hub or wheel.

Comment: Thanks for answer, may be it inclusive warranty conditions?
It wasn't buyed separate, it was on Specialized

Comment: For a new bike this would be an obvious warranty issue, but since Ultegra 67xx was superseded with 6800 at 2013, I'd expect that the warranty would have expired.

Comment: I don't know. Specialized's warranties are pretty good, but the site https://www.specialized.com/us/en/faq#warranty there says wheels would only have a 1 year warranty, and only for the original owner. I would suggest getting the seller to try a warranty claim first, unless it's cheap enough you are willing to replace the hub/wheel at cost.

Comment: I agree that the seller could try to warranty it. Even if the warranty has run out, this could be covered by general product liability or the wheel replacement program mentioned on that page. This is a clear design and manufacturing defect.

Comment: It is 2013 model, I don't think that it is covered by warranty